# Program type already present: com.sun.activation.registries.MailcapTokenizer

Tags: java, android, android-gradle-plugin

Also tell me the reason for this error. And what is the difference between MailcapTokenizer and LineTokenizer

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'

```
packagingOptions {
    exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
    exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
    exclude 'META-INF/notice.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/license.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/dependencies.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/LGPL2.1'
}

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.hitmusicusa"
    minSdkVersion 14
    targetSdkVersion 26
    multiDexEnabled true

}

buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        proguardFiles 'proguard-project.txt'
    }
}
```

}

dependencies {
    implementation project(':core')

```
implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:12.0.1'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:17.1.1'
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
implementation 'com.google.guava:guava:25.0-android'

implementation 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore:4.4.5'
implementation 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.5'
implementation 'com.jeremyfeinstein.slidingmenu:library:1.3@aar'
implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.0'
implementation "com.google.guava:guava:23.0"
implementation('org.simpleframework:simple-xml:2.7.1') {
    exclude group: 'stax', module: 'stax-api'
    exclude group: 'xpp3', module: 'xpp3'
}

implementation 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpmime:4.5.2'
implementation 'com.j256.ormlite:ormlite-core:5.1'
implementation 'org.jbundle.util.osgi.wrapped:org.jbundle.util.osgi.wrapped.org.apache.http.client:4.1.2'
implementation 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient-android:4.3.5'
implementation 'com.j256.ormlite:ormlite-android:5.1'
```

}